# How do I make a component like this in Eclipse Java WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtree, windowbuilder

I would like to make such a tree-like component with many roots. What component should I use? JTree doesnt allow multiple parents.

## [image]

Comment: Perhaps that is a JTree with three children and you don't actually see the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a normal JTree and set the [setRootVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setRootVisible(boolean)) property to false

```
 jTree.setRootVisible(false);
```

Example

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();

   ///adding mock data
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent" + i);
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            parent.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child" + j));
        }
        root.add(parent);
    }

    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree(model);

    tree.setRootVisible(false);//To hide root

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    frame.setTitle("Tree RootHide Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Example Output

[image: Tree with root hidden mocks as Multiple root]